# How to improve iText performance when creating tables

Tags: c#, .net, performance, itext7

Hey awesome Stackoverflow people

I am currently evaluating if we should use iText 7.1.9 for Java or C#.
To do this, I created a test case where I write a single PDF with a bunch of pages, each containing a big table (code below).

In Java, creating a PDF with x pages yields the following results:

- 1 page: 0 sec
- 10 pages: 1 sec
- 100 pages: 5 sec
- 1000 pages: 23 sec

This is reasonably performant. However, when I ported the exact same code to C# .Net, I got quite the shock:

- 1 page: 0 sec
- 10 pages: 1 sec
- 100 pages: 10 sec
- 1000 pages: 96 sec

The PDFs created with Java have the same size as the C# ones and the files look exactly the same.
C# however seems to scale linearly while Java somehow manages to optimize bigger PDFs.

Since we'd rather use C# the questions are:

1. What the hell is going on?
2. Is there anything I have to do to achieve roughly the same performance as with Java?

**Java code:**

```
package pcm;

import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.ColorConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfAConformanceLevel;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputIntent;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfString;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfViewerPreferences;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.AreaBreak;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.AreaBreakType;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.UnitValue;
import com.itextpdf.pdfa.PdfADocument;

public class PcmSimple {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        long startTime, elapsedTime;

        try {           
            for(int i=1; i<=1000; i*=10) {
                startTime = System.nanoTime();
                createPdf("D:\\Pcm Test", i);           
                elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

                System.out.println(String.format("%04d pages: %02d sec", i, NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(elapsedTime)));
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + ": " + ex.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

    private static void createPdf(String path, int numberOfPages) throws IOException {
        PdfFont fontBold = PdfFontFactory.createFont("resources/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf", true);
        PdfFont fontComic = PdfFontFactory.createFont("resources/fonts/comic-sans-ms_[allfont.de].ttf", true);

        // Set up the document.     
        PdfADocument pdfDocument = new PdfADocument(
                new PdfWriter(String.format("%s\\java_%d_pages.pdf", path, numberOfPages)), 
                PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3B, 
                new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", 
                        new FileInputStream("resources/color/sRGB_CS_profile.icm")));

        pdfDocument.setTagged();
        pdfDocument.getDocumentInfo().setTitle("Reference Document");
        pdfDocument.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().setDisplayDocTitle(true));
        pdfDocument.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("en-US"));

        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

        // Add a table to every page.
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
            Table table = new Table(5);
            table.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {                
                Cell cell = new Cell(2, 1)
                        .add(new Paragraph("Header " + j).setMultipliedLeading(0.5f))
                        .setFont(fontBold)
                        .setFontSize(20)
                        .setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.CYAN);

                table.addHeaderCell(cell);
            }

            for(int j=0; j<225; j++) {              
                Cell cell = new Cell()
                        .add(new Paragraph("Test " + j).setMultipliedLeading(0.5f))
                        .setFont(fontComic)
                        .setPaddingTop(4.1f);

                table.addCell(cell);
            }

            document.add(table);
            document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
        }

        document.close();
    }
}
```

**C# .Net Code:**

```
using iText.Kernel.Colors;
using iText.Kernel.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using iText.Layout.Properties;
using iText.Pdfa;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace PCM_Performance_Test_Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime startTime;
            long elapsedTime;

            try
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i *= 10)
                {
                    startTime = DateTime.Now;
                    CreatePdf("D:\\Pcm Test", i);
                    elapsedTime = (long)(DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds;

                    Console.WriteLine($"{i:d04} pages: {elapsedTime:d02} sec");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ": " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.Read();
            }
        }

        private static void CreatePdf(String path, int numberOfPages)
        {
            PdfFont fontBold = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("resources/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf", true);
            PdfFont fontComic = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("resources/fonts/comic-sans-ms_[allfont.de].ttf", true);

            // Set up the document.     
            PdfADocument pdfDocument = new PdfADocument(
                    new PdfWriter($"{path}\\csharp_{numberOfPages}_pages.pdf"),
                    PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3B,
                    new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1",
                            new FileStream("resources/color/sRGB_CS_profile.icm", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)));

            pdfDocument.SetTagged();
            pdfDocument.GetDocumentInfo().SetTitle("Reference Document");
            pdfDocument.GetCatalog().SetViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().SetDisplayDocTitle(true));
            pdfDocument.GetCatalog().SetLang(new PdfString("en-US"));

            Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

            // Add a table to every page.
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++)
            {
                Table table = new Table(5);
                table.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));

                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    Cell cell = new Cell(2, 1)
                            .Add(new Paragraph("Header " + j).SetMultipliedLeading(0.5f))
                            .SetFont(fontBold)
                            .SetFontSize(20)
                            .SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.CYAN);

                    table.AddHeaderCell(cell);
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < 225; j++)
                {
                    Cell cell = new Cell()
                            .Add(new Paragraph("Test " + j).SetMultipliedLeading(0.5f))
                            .SetFont(fontComic)
                            .SetPaddingTop(4.1f);

                    table.AddCell(cell);
                }

                document.Add(table);
                document.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
            }

            document.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can run it without the `try...catch` what is the time for 1000 pages ? It is always more efficient to put the `try...catch` only where it need to be and only catch the error type you expect to catch not all of them using `Exception`

Comment: Considering that the situation gets worse the more content there is (the factor rising from 1 to more than 4), this looks like either an issue with collection access or with system resources. The former should be looked at by the iText people, for the latter please inspect in particular memory settings and usage.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed question and very clear code example. I'll take this up internally (QA Engineer @ iText Software, and response time is definitely a Non-functional Requirement - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement)

Comment: @Amedee I think I've figured out what's happening.
It wasn't clear on my shitty 2-core work computer, but I've now run the tests on my i9-9900K@4.7GHz. The C#-Tests ran as expected: They consumed 100% of one logical core. The Java test were interesting: They started normally but at some point during the 10'000 pages (yes, I've upped the amount), Java switched to multithreading, using all my 16 logical cores, consuming 80% of my total CPU power, which explains how Java scales better than linearly! So, is this a weird Java feature or does iText for Java do this?

Comment: I don't know yet, I'm still on my morning coffee. :) The source code of the Java and .NET versions are kept as closely equivalent as possible, going as far as automatically converting the Java code to C# with a (heavily customized) conversion tool called Sharpen (https://medium.com/@pauldbau/a-guide-to-sharpen-a-great-tool-for-converting-java-to-c-1a1892a239ca). This is done for the purpose of maintainability. In iText 5 we were still manually porting from Java to C#, and the C# version was often weeks behind the Java version. Now it's just minutes behind. (Continued)

Comment: Automatic conversion of Java code to syntactically equivalent C# code may in some rare cases lead to slightly sub-optimal code in terms of performance, because of the little idiosyncrasies of each language and platform. Which is why we are making constant improvements to our porting tool, and Stack Overflow questions like this help us pinpoint possible improvements. Also, in some cases the best possible C# code is radically different from the Java code, and in those cases we excluded that class from autoporting and we do manual porting.

Comment: You can deduce all of that from the commits in the public git repository of iText 7 .NET on GitHub: look at all the commits that update the file `port-hash`, or the commit messages "Autoported commit. Original commit hash: [abc1234]".

Comment: @Amedee Yeah, never mind, sorry. It was Java needing 6.5 GB memory. Since my first tests only allocated 4 GB, the GC was using all CPUs at the end to try freeing some resources. When executed with 8 GB (-Xmx8g), it uses 1 CPU.
Java needs 133 seconds for 10'000 pages while C# needs 691 seconds.
I guess we're just gonna roll with Java ;)

Comment: Nevertheless I'm going to try out your code on the beefiest AWS instance that I can get my hands on.

Comment: I'm going to make a few changes to your code: (1) use `PdfDocument` instead of `PdfADocument`, to get rid of the `pdfa` dependency (2) don't use `PdfFont` because I don't have your font files and I'm not going to hunt for them online (3) no `PdfOutputIntent`, again an external resource I can drop (4) I'm not setting any document properties (5) my loop is `for (int i = 1; i <= 10_000; i *= 2)` (6) I'm making the code a bit more Linux friendly. Will report back the results.

Comment: I'm also extracting the `Table`, you create it each time again in each loop, I create a `Table` object only once before the loop and add that one same object to each page. That's only a 1.8% performance improvement.

Comment: I can't get the C# code to work on my Linux machine. Literally. As in: I copy/pasted your code in Rider, it compiles, but how do I get `static void Main` to run? I have never done any .NET development before, I am totally unfamiliar with the ecosystem.

Comment: Found it. I had to change the project from "Class library" to "Console application".

Comment: As I wrote, I don't do `*=10` in the `for` loop, I use `*=2`, to get more test results. I got the code running in Java and .NET, and for 8192 pages: Java does it in 53 seconds, .NET needs 618 seconds. For larger numbers of pages, the ratio .NET/Java stabilizes to a value of 5.83 (in other words: Java is almost 6 times faster). In other words, the performance difference you see with regards to adding tables to pages, is **confirmed**.

Answer (score 1):

It's not your code, it's the library, I setup a test project and best I could do was shave off around 20%, but that doesn't come close to the performance of the java version...

- 0001 pages: 0.1133129
- 0010 pages: 0.9318324
- 0100 pages: 8.2051265
- 1000 pages: 80.615356

---

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime startTime;
    TimeSpan elapsedTime;
    int xy = 1000;
    try
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= xy; i *= 10)
        {
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            CreatePdf("D:\\Pcm Test", i);
            elapsedTime = (DateTime.Now - startTime);

            Console.WriteLine($"{i:d04} pages: {elapsedTime.TotalSeconds}.{elapsedTime.Milliseconds}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ": " + ex.StackTrace);
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public static void CreatePdf(String path, int numberOfPages)
{
    PdfFont fontBold = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(@"C:\Users\Aydin\Desktop\arialbd.ttf", true);
    PdfFont fontComic = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(@"C:\Users\Aydin\Desktop\calibri.ttf", true);
    // Set up the document.     

    using (var rgbCSProfile = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Aydin\Downloads\sRGB_CS_profile.icm", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter($"{path}\\csharp_{numberOfPages}_pages.pdf"))
    {
        PdfADocument pdfDocument = new PdfADocument(pdfWriter, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3B, new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", rgbCSProfile));
        pdfDocument.SetTagged();
        pdfDocument.GetDocumentInfo().SetTitle("Reference Document");
        pdfDocument.GetCatalog().SetViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().SetDisplayDocTitle(true));
        pdfDocument.GetCatalog().SetLang(new PdfString("en-US"));

        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

        // Add a table to every page.
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++)
        {

            Table table = new Table(5, true);
            table.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));

            document.Add(table);

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                Cell cell = new Cell(2, 1)
                        .Add(new Paragraph("Header " + j).SetMultipliedLeading(0.5f))
                        .SetFont(fontBold)
                        .SetFontSize(20)
                        .SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.CYAN);

                table.AddHeaderCell(cell);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 225; j++)
            {
                if (j % 15 == 0) table.Flush();

                Cell cell = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("Test " + j)
                                      .SetMultipliedLeading(0.5f))
                                      .SetFont(fontComic)
                                      .SetPaddingTop(4.1f);

                table.AddCell(cell);
            }

            table.Complete();
            document.Flush();
            document.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
        }
        document.Close();
    }
}
// Define other methods and classes here
```

Comment: Apparently it's not the library, it's the language. Still needs to be confirmed but preliminary results of the OP point very suggestively in that direction.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Not sure if this helps but the bottleneck is at `document.Add(table);` `document.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));` I used `MiniProfiler` to test each block of code and the most time consuming part was always that block of code

Comment: I am not familiar with MiniProfiler or with the .NET ecosystem at large (being a Linux user) but I'll have a look, thanks.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, all it is, is just a library that allows you to test the performance of individual blocks of code by essentially running a stopwatch against blocks of code you specify

Comment: I got Darkmessage's code running in Rider, and in a Linux shell as a .NET Core console application. Now, how do I start using your MiniProfiler? Please be patient with me, I have absolutely zero hands-on experience with .NET development.

Comment: Okay, found it. I had some difficulty trying to figure out how to install NuGet packages, but I finally found how to do that in Rider. And then I followed the instructions on https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/ConsoleDotNetCore

Comment: How do I view the results? `Console.WriteLine(profiler.RenderPlainText());` or `Console.WriteLine(MiniProfiler.Current.RenderPlainText());` don't print a profiler tree.

Comment: It is logical that the bottleneck is at `document.Add(table); document.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));` because that is the main part of the code, everything else is just boilerplate. We need to go deeper.