# iText 7 PDF document generation performance issue

Tags: performance, itext7

I've read the following post regarding the iText 7 performance issue:
[How to improve iText performance when creating tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59307147/how-to-improve-itext-performance-when-creating-tables)

Since I can't add comments on that same thread, I've to create a new thread. My question is: is there any conclusion on how to further improve the performance with the .NET library? I'm in the same situation and with similar performance. My application will need to produce PDF report with even more complex table structures.

Thanks for any helps!

Comment: Well as you can see from the comments over there, I got stuck at running MiniProfiler. I'm more of a Linux/Java type myself, so I'm not familiar with the .NET ecosystem.
But anyway. Are you an iText customer? If you are, then you have a support contract and you can contact iText Software directly. For this specific question, I really recommend that you do that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion.